# Calculating Total using IIF expression

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report section where it calculate the TOTAL column by dividing the total of "Call Opportunities (PW)" and "LCAs Accepted(PW)". For example, 735.0 / 67 should be 9.1, but it is averaging it.  I have to code below, but not sure how to change the calculation as mentioned above.

[image]
[image]
    =iif(Fields!Lower_Cost_Alternative_Metrics.Value="Call Opportunities (PW)",
    Sum(Fields!CM.Value+Fields!JAX.Value+Fields!OKC.Value+Fields!OP.Value+Fields!WAU.Value+Fields!MKE.Value),
iif(Fields!Lower_Cost_Alternative_Metrics.Value="LCAs Accepted(PW)",
    Sum(Fields!CM.Value+Fields!JAX.Value+Fields!OKC.Value+Fields!OP.Value+Fields!WAU.Value+Fields!MKE.Value),
iif(Fields!Lower_Cost_Alternative_Metrics.Value="Acceptance Rate (PW)",
Sum(Fields!CM.Value+Fields!JAX.Value+Fields!OKC.Value+Fields!OP.Value+Fields!WAU.Value+Fields!MKE.Value)/6,
    Sum(Fields!CM.Value+Fields!JAX.Value+Fields!OKC.Value+Fields!OP.Value+Fields!WAU.Value+Fields!MKE.Value)/6)))

Answer (score 0):

For each field on the Acceptance row I would utilise "reportitems" in the expression. First denote the name of each item divide / by, then use these names within an expression using reportitems. I have enclosed a more detailed jpg.[image]

Comment: Thanks Philip Webb.. I've used report!tems before I'm just not sure how to lay it out in expression.

Comment: Philup the design template is only 1 line so the Call Opportunities, LCA Accepted, Acceptance rate is coming from SQL script (pivot) and unioned.